# How do you direct a user back to the beginning of a nested if statement?

Tags: ruby, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to create one of my first apps to help me work through understanding some core concepts of Ruby. This is pretty simple and self explanatory to most of you guys, I have no doubt. Any help is greatly appreciated. I apologize if this seems silly, I am just starting out and doing my best to figure this out. I want to add the option to see the list if they answer "no" to the "Do you want to keep adding fruits to your list?". I would also like the app, at the end, the final else statement, to bring the user back up to the "Then tell me another of you favorite fruits! (Type 'done' to get out)" message.  How do I do this?

```
# This app was created by: Daniel Horowitz

fruits = []

puts "Please tell me what one of your favorite fruits are... Do tell."
input = gets.chomp
fruits << input

puts "Yummy, that sounds delicious. You must tell me another!"
input = gets.chomp
fruits << input

puts "Do you want to keep adding fruits to your list?"
answer = gets.chomp.downcase

if answer == "yes"
  puts "Then tell me another of your favorites fruits! (Type 'done' to get out)"
  input = gets.chomp
  while input != "done"
    fruits << input
    puts "Would you like to see a list of you most favorite fruits?"
    input2 = gets.chomp.downcase
    if input2 == "yes"
      puts "These are your most dilectably delicious favorite fruits: #{fruits}"
    else

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fruits = []

loop do # endless loop; see break
  puts "Type your fave fruit or “done” to exit:"
  input = gets.chomp

  break if input == 'done' # break a loop if “done” was entered
  fruits << input
end

puts "Would you like to see a list of you most favorite fruits?"
if gets.chomp.downcase == "yes"
  puts "These are your most dilectably delicious favorite fruits: #{fruits}"
end
```

Run:

```
# Type your fave fruit or “done” to exit:
Apple
# Type your fave fruit or “done” to exit:
Orange
# Type your fave fruit or “done” to exit:
done
# Would you like to see a list of you most favorite fruits?
yes
# These are your most dilectably delicious favorite fruits: ["Apple", "Orange"]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very useful, thank you for taking the time to help me learn a little more!